# Changing endpoint in Web.config during deployment with a Azure Powershell script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, azure, web-config, web-deployment

I recently created a Powershell script that deploys my Web Application (ASP.NET MVC) to Azure. It works like it should, but I figured out that it would improve the script a lot by being able to change the endpoint in the Web.config file during deployment, i.e. the script prompts the user for the address. The Web.config section looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:10421/MyService" binding="binding" bindingConfiguration="foo" contract="bar" name="id" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I would like to change the endpoint address with my script.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet to load your configuration file, access the property and change it and finally write it back using the [Set-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113392) cmdlet:

```
[xml]$content = (Get-Content 'your_file')
$content.configuration.'system.serviceModel'.client.endpoint.address = 'YourNewAdress'
$content | Set-Content 'your_file'
```

Note: I asume that the `system.serviceModel` is within the `configuration` node. If not, omit that.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the answer. I will try it and get back to you shortly.
But won't this override the file itself?, i.e. this is just a way to edit the address, but then I'll have to build the project to deploy. So in the end this is the same way as just editing the endpoint myself with the desired address -> deploy -> revert the address back to "http://localhost:10421/MyService"?

Comment: @DKo Yes, it will just override the file itself. You could also bootstrap `WCF` endpoints programmatically in `C#`, maybe you are looking for that?